# Create an object with JSON - Exception received

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Given a string keyString, I do in my Java program the following:

```
ObjectId key = new Gson().fromJson(keyString, ObjectId.class);
```

But for this line I get this exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3

What does that mean, and what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Could you give the complete String "keyString"?

Comment: Basically it could be any string given by user, but for the sake of the discussion, I got this error when keyString was "abc"

Comment: "abc"?? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok...so can you please explain what a valid json is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromJson` method awaits a `json` object. This means a string in `json` format and specifically it needs to start with `{` (and not `[`).

This is valid:

```
{ 'id': '1234'}
```

This is not valid:

```
[{ 'id': '1234'}]
```

This is also not valid:

```
abc
```

Answer (score 2):

It means your JSON does not start with "{".  Objects in JSON look something like this:

```
{
  "name" : "john"
}
```